# How to convert a matrix in matlab to a double[,] array in C#/.NET?

Tags: c#, arrays, matlab, matrix

How can I convert matrix of type MWArray (returned from matlab runtime) to a 2-dim array (double[,]) in C#?

I am working on the simplest matlab & .NET integration as explained in:
http://domoreinlesstime.wordpress.com/2013/01/26/access-matlab-from-c/

With the following statement I can convert the variable *result* of type MWArray to a 1-dim array:

```
double[] arr = (double[])((MWNumericArray)result).ToVector(MWArrayComponent.Real);
```

Is there a simple way to convert *result* into a 2-dim array in C#?

Answer (score 7):

The following should be enough (worked for me):

```
double[,] arr = (double[,])((MWNumericArray)result).ToArray(MWArrayComponent.Real);
```

Answer (score -2):

Finally, I found the answer here:

calling matlab functions from .NET
http://forum.finaquant.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1217

```
double[] arr = (double[])((MWNumericArray)result).ToVector(MWArrayComponent.Real);

// convert 1-dim array (vector) to 2-dim array
double[] vec = (double[])((MWNumericArray)M).ToVector(MWArrayComponent.Real);
double[,] mat = new double[rows, cols];

for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
    {
        mat[j, i] = vec[i * cols + j + 1];
    }
}
```